# sql.Connection is not a constructor [nodejs expressjs and SqlServer] ---

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, google-api-nodejs-client, nodejs-server

I am trying to write a backend API in node and express JS to connect to SQL Server[with windows authentication] and fetch data. The error message is --

```
const poolPromise = new sql.Connection(config)
TypeError: sql.Connection is not a constructor
```

The relevant config file code is dbConfig.js :

```
const sql = require('msnodesqlv8')

const config = {
    database: 'ApiDemoDB',
    server: '.\\SQLEXPRESS',
    driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
    options: {
      trustedConnection: true
    }

  }

  const poolPromise = new sql.Connection(config) <-------this line error
  .connect()
  .then(pool => {
    console.log('Connected to MSSQL')
    return pool
  })
  .catch(err => console.log('Database Connection Failed! Bad Config!:  ', err))

  module.exports = {
    sql, poolPromise
  }
```

What is the meaning of this error message? sql.Connection is not supposed to take any parameter[config]? I don't get it, what am I supposed to do differently here? What additional code changes do I have to make in order to get this working? Can you please help me solve this problem so that the API can connect to the mssql database? As you can see, as of now I have very little code. Barebones.

Thanking you in advance.

*********************************** EDIT ***********************************
I have changed the code around quite a bit.

My dbconfig.js file is now as:

```
const sql = require('mssql');
const msnodesqlv8=require('msnodesqlv8');

var dbconfig = {
    server: 'localhost',
    database: 'ApiDemoDB',
    driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
    options: {

      enableArithAbort:true,
      trustedConnection: true,
      instancename:'SQLEXPRESS'
    },
    port:1433

  }

module.exports=dbconfig;
```

And then a separate dbconnect.js file as:

```
var sql = require("mssql/msnodesqlv8")
var dbConfig = require("./dbConfig")

var dbConnect = new sql.connect(dbConfig,
  function(err)
   {
     if(err){
       console.log("Error while connecting to database:  " + err)
     }else{
       console.log("connected to database:  " + dbConfig.server)
     }
   }
)
module.exports = dbConnect
```

Now, the error that I have is ->

***Error while connecting to database:  ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)***

What does this even mean. It's pointing to the dbconfig file, but what changes to be written there, can you suggest me? Thanks

Comment: here, check the answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58176669/885626

Comment: hi @Ric saw the marked answer there; If I use connectionPool, then the error message simply changes to

const poolPromise = new sql.ConnectionPool(config)
TypeError: sql.ConnectionPool is not a constructor

this is how I am stuck

Comment: pl check out the EDIT portion of original post. I have added changed code there as it stands now ....

Comment: better error, some posts are already covering this, please check
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50853516/nodejs-connection-with-mssql-showing-error

Comment: hi @Ric performed those setting changes on my mssql instance. Now error is  
.


Error while connecting to database:  ConnectionError: Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.

Comment: Does your database have a username password? you'll need to add this to the connection string

Comment: no, @Ric  mine is Windows Authentication. I don't have to provide any username password for connecting ....

Comment: changing 2 things has finally got this working. 1. in the dbconfig file, const poolPromise=new sql.ConnectionPool(......

and

manually putting the port number from sql server from the TCP/IP properties tab for IPv9 and IPvAll.
It's working now,